# Cannot post data to mlab in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a simple div with content editable and I get whatever the user has typed in that div with an onclick event. I want to send that data to my database in Mlab, I am hosting my application on Heroku. Currently when I try to post the data, I get a 404 error and after a couple of seconds I get `GET http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and I don't know why, since I am able to retrieve the already existing data via a get request. What am I doing wrong here and how can I make that post request successfully? Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class CommentBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      state = {
        userComments: []
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('https://backend-express.herokuapp.com/userComments');
            this.setState({...this.state, userComments: res.data})
          };
          fetchPosts();
        }

          getCommentData = () => {
            const commentContent = document.querySelector(".comment-box-container__div-comment-box").textContent;
            axios.post('https://backend-express.herokuapp.com/userComments', { commentContent })
           }


    render() {

        return(
            <div className="comment-box-container">
             <div className="comment-box-container__div">
             <button className="comment-box-container__post-comment-btn" onClick={this.getCommentData}> Post Comment</button>
             <div className="comment-box-container__div-comment-box" contentEditable="true"></div>
             </div>

             <div className="comment-box-container__show-coments-section">
             {this.state.userComments.map(comment => 
             <section>
            <h3>{comment.date}</h3>
            {comment.title}
            </section>
            )}
             </div>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

and my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const itemRoutes = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());



mongoose.connect("mongodb://admin:user@password/fghfghfhf", { useNewUrlParser: true } )

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

// Serve static assets
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}


itemRoutes.route('/').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("posts");
  let response = await collection.find({})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});

itemRoutes.route('/userComments').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("user_comments");
  let response = await collection.find({})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});


app.use('/', itemRoutes);
app.use('/userComments', itemRoutes);



app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
})
```

Comment: In your server why you are using `/userComments.get()` while your are sending post request from axios?

Comment: because I also need to dislpay them

Comment: Okay. Then first you do not have matching post request in api. second you need to change `app.post('/userComments').post((req,res)=>{})`. Third, after posing data to database, You can again fire `get()` request of api so that you can get data back too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use post with express to fetch post data

```
  app.post('/userComments', function(req, res) {
     //Perform your actions here
     // res.body contains the sent data

   });
```

Comment: thank you, but how will I send the data from the div that I have obtained in my react component to the express post method? Is it possible?

Comment: You have that down. axios.post('Url', Object)